# Rails pass more than one parameter into dry-monads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monads

Let's assume I've got below monad class:

```
require 'dry-monads'
require 'dry/monads/all'

module Test
  class MonadsClass
    include Dry::Monads

    def initialize(signees)
      @signees = signees
    end

    def call
      Success(signees)
        .bind(method(:fetch_template))
        .bind(method(:envelope_from_template))
    end

    attr_reader :signees

    private

    def fetch_template(signees)
      key = "template_#{signees.size}".to_sym
      template_id = Rails.application.credentials.some_api.fetch(key)

      Success(template_id: template_id, key: key)
    end

    def envelope_from_template(template_id:, key:)
      response = some_api.copy_from_template(template_id, key)

      response.failure? ? Failure(response.failure) : Success(response.value!)
    end
  end
end
```

Why in this combination I'm getting strange error of:

```
Failure/Error:
def envelope_from_template(template_id:, key:)
  response = some_api.copy_from_template(template_id)

  response.failure? ? Failure(response.failure) : Success(response.value!)
end

ArgumentError:
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: template_id, key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are expecting it to pass kwargs (keyword arguments) but it is passing a `Hash`. Ruby 2.7 deprecated "automatic conversion" of Hash to kwargs and ruby 3.0 removed it completely. You can read more about the separation of positional and keyword arguments [Here](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/)

In other words you are expecting it to call

```
envelope_from_template(template_id: 123, key: 'abc')
```

but you are actually calling

```
envelope_from_template({template_id: 123, key: 'abc'})
```

Instead you have a couple options which should work:

- Option 1 (call `bind` with a block)

```
def call
  Success(signees)
    .bind(method(:fetch_template))
    .bind {|h| envelope_from_template(**h) }
end
```

- Option 2 - Change the method signature and then use `Hash` access methods in the body

```
def envelope_from_template(params)
  response = some_api.copy_from_template(params.values_at(:template_id, :key))

  response.failure? ? Failure(response.failure) : Success(response.value!)
end
```

Comment: That sucks because this limits the flexibility of monads. Anyway, thanks for great explanation and bring attention to the problem!